# Google bots get 503 errors while indexing my website

Tags: php, laravel, googlebot, http-status-code-503

While google (or any other robot) is crawling my website developed using Laravel, it gets 503 Server Unavailable error. I can visit my website without any problem and do not get any error: http://www.kurumyonetimsistemi.com

How can I fix this problem?

Edit:

503 error is because I am redirecting not found pages to a custom page. If I remove this redirect, robots get 500 Internal Server Error. But I can display my website on a browser without problem.

Comment: In the Google webmaster dashboard you can find the entire error. Please post this error, because we can't help you if you don't provide more information.

Comment: It just says: Google couldn't follow your URL because it redirected too many times. I have checked for errors using a website and it reports: Broken link: http://www.kurumyonetimsistemi.com/ 503 Server Unavailable

Comment: May be you have custom settings for robots. do you have [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608) file?

Comment: Yes, it contains:

User-agent: *
Allow: *

Comment: Funny.  Your url /robots.txt seems to work fine and returns 200

Comment: Tried both www and non-www domains and both ok

Comment: But somehow robots get 403 error. Does laravel have any other setting or configuration for robots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a while of searching, I have found the problem. I was getting the visitors browser language and stroing it as a cookie.
This process causes errors for robots. If I remove the code, the problem is solved.